# Adjust layout buttons while softkeyboard is on in android

Tags: android, view, textbox, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

i am developing an android app where i have a Text box.. All i want is, Onclick of that Text box, the layout buttons which are below the Keyboard should be visible along with the keyboard buttons since they are hidden by the keyboard. I am using the below code in xml.

```
     <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_weight=".20">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="Message : "
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".80"
    android:background="@drawable/albgbckgrnd"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight=".33"           
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Not Getting how to do it! Pls Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
"adjustResize"
```

According to the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

> The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.

Add this to your activity in manifest file like this

```
  <activity android:name="YourActivityName" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Update your layout like this

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="Message : "
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".80"
        android:background="#ff00"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post the layout you are using.

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child...got this error